# Count numbers present in each line for unique String using shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, awk

I am using unix shell script and have an Input File with data as:

```
3:abc
1:xyz
1:abc
2:def
10:xyz
```

My expected output is:

```
4:abc
11:xyz
2:def
```

i.e. Find unique string on each line after delimiter and add up the numbers before that. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using `awk`.  It accumulates the values into an array.

```
awk -F ":" '{count[$2]+=$1} END {for (key in count) print key, count[key]}' awk_data.txt
```

And here is a version, using a `bash` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A count
while read line; do
    key=${line##*:}
    cnt=${line%%:*}
    count[$key]=$(($cnt + ${count[$key]=0}))
done < "$1"
for K in "${!count[@]}"; do echo $K ${count[$K]}; done
```

And another `bash` version from the comments, using `IFS=:`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A count
while IFS=: read -r cnt key; do
    count[$key]=$(($cnt + ${count[$key]=0}))
done < "$1"
for K in "${!count[@]}"; do echo $K ${count[$K]}; done
```

Comment: This works like charm. lovely ! thank you Stephen.

Comment: Why not `IFS=: read -r CNT key`

Comment: @iruvar, I sadly (and likely in-advisedly) tend to avoid IFS because of the side effects, that can cause weirdness if you forget the `unset`.  But a fair comment, I added version using `IFS=:`

Comment: You can scope IFS to just the `read` statement and avoid the need to unset using `while IFS=: read -r cnt key`

Comment: @iruvar, It is always a good day when you learn something new.  Thanks!

Comment: A `IFS=: read -r CNT key` doesn't change IFS in the present shell. You can test it with: `IFS=: read a b c < <(echo "one:two:333"); echo "$IFS" | od -vAn -tx1c`

Answer (score 3):

You may also want to take a loot at GNU **datamash** utility. Example (table.txt from PO):

```
$ sort -t: -k 2 table.txt | datamash -t: -g 2 sum 1 collapse 1
abc:4:1,3
def:2:2
xyz:11:10,1
```

- `-t:` field delimiter is :
- `-g 2` group by the (previously sorted) second column
- `sum 1` sum the correspondent values in column 1
- `collapse 1` and also collapse them in a "," separate list